# Smartphones Unique features

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios

i am developing a project for smartphones (mostly android) and I looking for features that can be considered unique and can not be easily changed by the user like the MAC address or the IP address. So far the only features I have fount is the:

- browser fingerpting
- Accelerator fingerprinting

Does anyone have any suggestion of any other feature that I can use ?

Comment: On iOS this is not possible, Apple has made any unique identifier unavailable for developers. On iOS your only hope is to generate an unique identifier yourself and store it in the keychain so it does not get removed when the app is deleted.